# Sound plays every other time the Video plays in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

In chrome (7.0.517.44) I am using the `<video>` tag and the audio will only play **every other time** the video is played.

**Why is the audio not always playing along with the video?**

In page:

```
<div id="VideoShow">
    <video id="VideoPlay" width=800 height=600></video>
</div>
```

On click this JS is run.

```
function playVideo(videoName) {
    $("#VideoShow").fadeIn(300);
    var Vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    Vid.src = videoName;
    Vid.play();
    Vid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
        closeVideo();
    }, false);
}

function closeVideo() {
    var Vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    Vid.removeEventListener('ended', arguments.callee, false);
    Vid.pause();
    $("#VideoShow").fadeOut(300);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem with the `<audio>` tag recently.  Although I wasn't able to determine the actual cause, I was able to work around the issue by removing the old `<audio>` element from the DOM and replacing it with an identical element immediately before each call to play().

Comment: Seems that recreating the video tag every time did the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

I continue to find inconsistencies with the behavior of these elements.

Have you tried waiting to run the .play() method until after you receive a [canplay](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#event-media-canplay) or [canplaythrough](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#event-media-canplaythrough) event?

Might be worth a shot.