# Chrome Not releasing Memory From <video> 

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, html5-video

I have a page that loads lots of videos. It only has to work in Chrome.

Every time a video is created I remove and recreate the video tag, to get around the problems address [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248404/sound-plays-every-other-time-the-video-plays-in-chrome)

however the memory used by chrome keeps going up every time a video is played, never getting released (Even if its the same video).

**How can I get Chrome to release this memory?**

Here is some code js/jQuery as to how I am adding and removing videos:

```
function playVideo(videoName) {
    $("#VideoShow").fadeIn(300).html("<video width=800 height=600><source src=\"" + videoName + "\"'></video>");
    var Vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    Vid.play();
    Vid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
        closeVideo();
    }, false);
}

function closeVideo() {
    var Vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    Vid.removeEventListener('ended', arguments.callee, false);
    $("#VideoShow").fadeOut(300).html("");
}
```

*I would guess this is a bug in chrome however I want to make sure I am not doing anything wrong before reporting it.*

Comment: This looks ok. Please report a bug at http://new.crbug.com. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT*** As of Chrome Update in January 2013, this memory leak has been fixed!

I have created a chromium issue regarding this:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=166830

It is due to the hardware acceleration, it isn't releasing the memory.

If you toggle "disable accelerated video decoding" feature under chrome://flags/ then it doesn't do it at all. It looks like one of the chromium devs are looking into it shortly